# Java Stream Api: Using reduce to fill a collection

Tags: java, java-stream

I am well aware of the collect() method and the Collectors object. However, I don't really understand why it's bad to use a reduce to populate a collection.

`       User u1 = new User ("Tom");
User u2 = new User ("Anna");
User u3 = new User ("Alice");

```
    BiFunction<Set<String>, User, Set<String>> accumulator = (acc, u) -> {
        acc.add(u.getLogin());
        return acc;
    };
    BinaryOperator<Set<String>> combiner = (s1, s2) -> {
        s1.addAll(s2);
        return s2;
    };

    Stream<User> stream = Stream.of(u1, u2, u3);
    Set<String> logins = new HashSet<>();
    stream.reduce(logins, accumulator, combiner);
    System.out.println(logins);// [Tom, Alice, Anna]`
```

Is this bad code design, or something else under the hood?

Is it true that accumulation should be done on an immutable object?

Comment: Why would you call `logins.addAll(logins)`?

Comment: accidental typo)

Comment: Letting aside that you should not use this approach (as has been answered already), the entire code displays a horrible coding style. It looks as if someone is trying really hard to destroy the benefits of the programming language constructs (i.e. expressiveness). Your code basically does `Set<String> logins = new HashSet<>(); Stream.of(u1, u2, u3) .reduce(logins, (acc, u) -> acc.add(u.getLogin()), (s1, s2) -> { s1.addAll(s2); return s2; });` and in this case, the additional variables do not make the code more readable.

Comment: But the correct approach is even simpler: `Set<String> logins = Stream.of(u1, u2, u3) .map(User::getLogin) .collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness):

> Side-effects in behavioral parameters to stream operations are, in general, discouraged, as they can often lead to unwitting violations of the statelessness requirement, as well as other thread-safety hazards.

It is much easier to parallelize calls to `.collect` and have a predictable order. On the other hand, the accumulator function passed to `reduce` should be [associative](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity) and it may not be called on elements in the stream in encounter order, especially for parallel processing.

Furthermore, the meaning of the `collect` operation is much clearer and it should be preferred when the intention is indeed to create a collection from the elements of the stream.

Comment: Does it follow from this that accumulation (U identity) should be done on an immutable object?

Comment: @clipper1995 Not necessarily, as you can perform copies instead of mutating.

Comment: You can make copies but that is going into the wrong direction. A typical reduction function will return either one of the incoming objects (unmodified) or a different object, which can be a newly constructed one. E.g. the “get first” or “get last” functions, `(a, b) -> a` and `(a, b) -> b`, or summing `(a, b) -> a + b` or `String::concat`, though the last one while formally correct is inefficient, so `collect(Collectors.joining())` is preferable in most situations. If you have to make copies, to alter the copies then, it’s a sign that `collect` would be more efficient.

Comment: @Holger, thank you. This question was just generated by a misunderstanding of why and when to use reduce(). I just always use Collectors, and I can't think of examples for using reduce().